# How to avoid deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' in C++

Tags: c++, c, arrays, char

I would like to call the following code in C++, which I cannot change:

```
void getAge(char *name)
{
// do something
}
```

When I call it with `getAge("hello");`, it has the following warning:

```
warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'
```

but there is no warning in C code. What is the difference, and how do I change the call to avoid the warning in C++?

Comment: Make the function parameter a `const char*`?

Comment: no, it is the function defined by others, can not be changed

Comment: In that case, cast the argument.

Comment: in that case take it up with whoever the people are who are doing this. You should get a warning with a decent C compiler anyway

Comment: When the pointer is not to be changed in the function, then it should be defined with `const char *`. Request "others" to change accordingly as it is a good practice

Comment: If there is no warning in C, you haven't been compiling with the right gcc options (`-Wwrite-strings`).

Comment: Can the function modify the string?

Comment: I think you should change the question as at the moment it reads as though it's your code. You don't say you can't change the function.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> the function […] can not be changed

Then write a wrapper around the function and copy the string – or, if you feel lucky (= you *know* that the string won’t be modified inside the original function), explicitly cast away const-ness:

```
void getAge(char const* name) {
    the_namespace::getAge(const_cast<char*>(name));
}
```

If you’re unsure whether the function modifies its parameters, use something like the following – however, if that’s the case then calling the function with a string literal (`getAge("hello")`) would have been invalid anyway.

```
void getAge(char const* name) {
    std::string buffer(name);
    the_namespace::getAge(&buffer[0]);
}
```

Here we copy the string into a modifiable buffer and pass an address to its first character to the original function.

Comment: @EricPostpischil And what does "copy the string" mean, otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

The safest way is to copy the string, then call the C function:

```
void getAgeSafe(const char* name)
{
  std::vector<char> tmp = name?
    std::vector<char>(name, name+1+strlen(name))
    :std::vector<char>();

  getAge( tmp.data() );
}
```

and call `getAgeSafe` from your C++ code.

A less safe way that relies on the C code *never* modifying the `char* name` would be to `const_cast`, again in a "wrapping" function:

```
void getAgeUnsafe(const char* name)
{
  getAge( const_cast<char*>(name) );
}
```

but this time the name is more scary, as is the operation.  If you call `getAge` with a compile time constant string like `"bob"`, if `getAge` modifies its input, undefined behavior results (this is true in both C and C++ -- C++ at least warns you about it).

Comment: `c_str()` returns a `const char *` so you'll get the same warning.  Passing `&name[0]` will work though.

Comment: @GuyGreer oops, fixed.  Even `data()` is `const` for `std::string`, so instead built a buffer of `std::vector<char>`.  (I'm not certain that `&name[0]` is guaranteed to be null-terminated by the standard?)

Comment: @Yakk It is in C++11 (null termination wasn’t the problem before either – contiguity of storage was). Your current code is unnecessarily convoluted in my opinion; just use the appropriate constructor to initialise the vector (of course that makes the null check impossible or at least harder).

Comment: @KonradRudolph Bah, read over the string *twice*, once to find the end, the other time to copy to the `std::vector`?  I suppose that does save on reallocations.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `getAge((char*)"hello")`.

Comment: Only if you know that the function won't try to modify the string. And you really should be using C++ casts.

Answer (score 0):

In c++ you can write it like this,
`void getAge(string name)
{
// do something
}`
and also include the header file `#include<string>` because you are using string now

Comment: the void getAge() method can not be changed

Comment: @nouney, the "can not be changed" information is not stated in the question yet, but only in the comments.